# name is too long to represent

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am getting this error on running my adf App.

```
<LifecycleImpl> <_handleException> ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InternalError: name is too long to represent
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:415)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.dispatch(RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:469)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:800)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:294)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:214)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InternalError: name is too long to represent
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: name is too long to represent
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspClassLoader.findClass(JspClassLoader.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspClassLoader.loadClass(JspClassLoader.java:33)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:531)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:281)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:524)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:444)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:184)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.IncludeTag.__include(IncludeTag.java:442)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RegionTag$1.call(RegionTag.java:153)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RegionTag$1.call(RegionTag.java:128)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.processRegion(UIXRegion.java:503)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RegionTag.doStartTag(RegionTag.java:127)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag10(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:540)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag9(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:506)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag4(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:298)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag3(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:242)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag1(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:158)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspx___tag0(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:104)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__suppwrkbnch_jspx._jspService(__suppwrkbnch_jspx.java:65)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    ... 55 more
```

Any Idea I have not changed anything from last run when it was working fine.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.InternalError: name is too long to represent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209718/java-lang-internalerror-name-is-too-long-to-represent)

Comment: Please submit full stack trace.

Comment: @Optional i have Updated stack trace...

Comment: Does this solve it? https://forums.oracle.com/thread/945287